# How to use DHT library dht-example.c for distributed hash tables

Tags: hashtable, p2p, bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I want to use [BitTorrent DHT library](https://github.com/jech/dht) as distributed hash tables from within a C program. Therefore I downloaded and compiled it on my machine - worked flawless.
Now I have an executable dht-example which outputs:

```
Usage: dht-example [-q] [-4] [-6] [-i filename] [-b address]...
                   port [address port]...
```

What can I do with this example?
How to play with the DHT:
Connect distributed machines, fill it or read hash tables from it?

Thanks lot
  Achim

Comment: Did you read the `readme` file in the repository? It appears to have a fairly well-documented API to follow... If you're asking how to execute one program from another, look at the [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) suite of system calls.

Comment: Oh yes, I've read the readme, there are all dht functions described well. Currently I reverse analyze the dht-example.c source code to see what is done, but this is complex for a newbe of distributed-hash-tables technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dht-example.c` is a minimalistic example provided in the mentioned DHT library.

After running `make` for compilatation you are supposed to run `./example-dht 6882 67.215.246.10 6881`. This will open a listening UDP socket on local port 6882 for talking to the DHT network.

But before your new peer is able to connect to the network, it needs at least one connected peer from which it can get more peers. This is where the third and fourth parameter/argument comes into action. It is the IP address and port combination of a known good node on the network, in this case `router.bittorrent.com`. This process is called bootstraping.

The program does not accept instructions from standard input, but instead via kernel signals `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. Use `kill -L` to list signal numbers on your machine and then command `ps aux | grep example-dht` while `example-dht` is running to obtain the process ID of `example-dht`.

For starting a search for peers of the infohash, hardcoded in `dht-example.c`, issue the command `kill -XX YYYYY`, where `XX` is the number of the `SIGUSR1` signal and `YYYYY` is the process ID of `dht-example`. Observe the standard output of the `dht-example` program.

For dumping other nodes in our bucket and bucket 0, issue the command `kill -XX YYYYY`, where `XX` is the number of the `SIGUSR2` signal and `YYYYY` is the process ID of `dht-example`. Observe the standard output of the `dht-example` program.

For stopping `dht-exmample`, issue the command `kill -XX YYYYY` where `XX` is the number of the `SIGINT` signal and `YYYYY` is the process ID of `dht-example`. Observe the standard output of the `dht-example` program.

Comment: Late but very helpful. Meanwhile I'm looking for a Go-implementation of a DHT to leave C behind - Thanks anyhow